Apache eCharts - custom width in bar chart
I'm migrating from chartjs to apache echarts.
Previously, I had this bar chart, where two datasets are present for each year. The requirement asked by our client is that, whenever a value is zero, the remaining bar should have all the space in the bin.
bar chart done with chartjs
How can I achieve this with echarts? Is using a custom dataset the only option?

You could split your data into 4 series:

Only data of dataset 1 present
Only data of dataset 2 present
Dataset 1 data when both are present
Dataset 2 data when both are present

Now you define a second xAxis with show: false such that series 1,2 and series 3,4 share one xAxis and make use of barGap to overlap bars on the same axis.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
    },
    {
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      data: ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: '1',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: '-100%',
      data: [120, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 330, 370]
    },
    {
      name: '1',
      type: 'bar',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      barGap: 0,
      data: [0, 232, 270, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      type: 'bar',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      data: [0, 180, 270, 0, 0]
    }
  ]
}

